# How to retrieve an attached gzipped JSON file with Python {requests,urllib4,mechanize ...}

Tags: python, json, gzip

I have an existing application that uses PyCurl to download gzipped JSON data via a REST type interface. This works well but is too slow for the desired use.

I'm trying to get an equivalent solution going that can use connection pooling. I have a simple example working with requests, but I don't see how to retrieve the attached gzipped JSON file that the returned header says is there.

My current sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests

headers = {"Authorization" :  "XXX thisworksIgeta200Response",
      "Content-type" : "application/json",
       "Accept" : "application/json"}

r = requests.get("https://longickyGUIDyURL.noname.com",headers=headers,verify=False,stream=True)

data = r.raw.read(decode_content=True)

print data
```

This produces an HTML page, not the JSON output I want. The relevant returned headers look like this:

```
'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename="9d5c3c68-0e88-4b2d-88b9-94534b6cb80d"
'content-encoding': 'gzip',
```

So: requests or urllib4 (tried this a bit but don't see many examples or much documentation) or something else?

Any guidance or recommendations would be most welcome!

Comment: Actually I'm expecting XML of a certain format but response.text gives HTML of a page, not the data I was expecting and that I get without a problem from the PyCurl implementation (changed to JSON by xmltodict, I forgot.) Is there some other response field that might have what I'm looking for?

Comment: The question is: where does gzip-decoded content go? The requests docs say it is "automatically decoded for you", but I'm not finding it. **response.content** gives the HTML downloaded, not the attached gzipped XML ...

Answer (score 0):

> The Content-Disposition response-header field has been proposed as a means for the origin server to suggest a default filename if the user requests that the content is saved to a file (rfc2616)

The filename in the header is no more than a suggestion for what the browser should save it as. There is no other file there. The content you got back is all there is. The `content-encoding: gzip` header means that the content of the page was gzip-encoded for transit, but the `requests` module will have decoded that for you.

So, if it's HTML and you were expecting JSON, you probably have the wrong URL.